# Angular 8 - show/hide dynamically created <div> based off it's id?

Tags: html, angular

In an Angular 8 component I'm dynamically creating `<table>` elements.

So x-amount of `<table>`'s are created (based off input array).

The last `<tr>` of each `<table>` contains a `<div>` and a button.

This `<div>` needs to toggle between show/hide when button is clicked.

I can show/hide all at the same time but need to show/hide a single one.

Is it possible show/hide the dynamically created `<div>` based off it's `id` ?

I believe something like this should work but to no avail.

```
<ng-template let-scores pTemplate="listItem">
...
<tr>
    <div id='scores.modRef'>my div</div>
    <button (click)='showHide(scores.modRef)'></button>
</tr>
```

```
showHide(modRef) {
    // hide the <div> with id == modRef
}
```

I have tried many different approaches but none work.

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the hiding/showing will probably be eventually sent to the backend, it would be a good idea to add an attribute to the scores and call it "visible", this way you can do this:

```
<ng-template let-scores pTemplate="listItem">
...
<tr>
    <div id='scores.modRef' *ngIf="scores.visible">my div</div>
    <button (click)='showHide(scores)'></button>
</tr>
```

Then:

```
showHide(scores) {
    scores.visible = !scores.visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<ng-template let-scores pTemplate="listItem">
...
<tr>
    <div [id]="scores.modRef" >my div</div>
    <button (click)='showHide(scores.modRef)'></button>
</tr>
```

```
status: boolean = false;

showHide(modRef) {
    // hide the <div> with id == modRef
    const nId = modRef.toString(); 
    this.status = !this.status;
    if(this.status) {
      document.getElementById(nId).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(nId).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this shows/hides all divs at the same time. I need to show/hide a single div

Comment: I have edit code. try this out. It worked in my case

Comment: Thanks again but results in Error when trying to get element by id and all divs keep changing

Comment: the edited code can be modified a bit to get it to work, but it's not the angular way to set the visibility of elements